# Excel: Group by column and Check if another Column contains a value higher or lower than 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet where I would like to create a second grouping depending on what value is present in the current group.

I would like to group column A and within each of those group check if a value in Column H is lower than 3.0 and if so have the Cell in Column Q be the Value 1. If not have the Cell have the Value 2.

The out come would be each grouping that have a value under 3.0 would be in group 1 and the rest would be in group 2
[Example of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCTk8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=IF(INDEX(FILTER($B$2:$B$16,$C$2:$C$16=1),COUNTIF($C$2:$C2,1))<3,1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that - I didnt think of using the 1-5 as my reference point

Comment: Have tried the code but it seems to think all the values are above 3 so sets it to 2